# Person extends Object but does not override toString

Tags: typescript

I would expect that defining a custom toString on a class that extends Object would override the toString function of the base class. However, this does not seem to apply.. Does anyone have an idea why this is the case?

Code is provided below:

```
class Person extends Object {
    constructor(public name:string){
        super(); 
        this.name = name;
    }

    public toString():string {
        return 'hi i am ' + this.name;
    }
}

var john = new Person("john");
console.log(john.toString());
```

This code outputs [object object], I would expect it to call the toString of the person class..

When I write this like the following code, it works, but what is the rationale?

```
class Person {
    constructor(public name:string){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public toString():string {
        return 'hi i am ' + this.name;
    }
}

var john = new Person("john");
console.log(john.toString());
```

Upon testing further, when I create a class that extends from Object, all of its methods are unavailable... So if I were to create a class like the following:

```
class Person extends Object {
    constructor(public name:string){
        super(); 
        this.name = name;
    }

    public toStringTest():string {
        return 'hi i am ' + this.name;
    }
}

var john = new Person("john");
console.log(john.toStringTest());   <-- ERROR HERE AT RUNTIME
```

It would error at runtime, stating that this method is not available..

Is this expected behavior?

For the record: I am using TypeScript in VSCode in NodeJS and transpiling from TS back to es5... Then I run it using NodeJS..

TIA,

John.

Comment: I guess this is because of the fact that in JavaScript the Person instance is an object, therefore its toString() is nearer in the prototypical inheritance tree than the prototype function toString of the class. But this is quite counter-intuitive...

Comment: Where are you seeing this behavior, this works as expected in Chrome, Edge and node ?

Comment: This is in typescript version 2.7.2 on NodeJS in VSCode..

Comment: As a matter of fact... using the extends Object creates an inheritance model directly to Object, invalidating all the methods of the class....

Comment: Wops, my bad, I was using as target `esnext`, if I compile with `es5` I get the same behavior as you.

Comment: Why do you extend `Object`?

Comment: Because I want to have access to all object function definitions but also override the toString method..

Comment: I noticed that the generated \_\_extends function in es5 actually wrongly sets up the Object as \_\_proto\_\_ object on the target instance, this should be the Person.prototype.. not the Object itself.. why is this?

Comment: It works as you expect it if you compile it with target `es6`.

Comment: Sure, but some of my code runs in 'older' browsers..

Comment: Classes already inherit from `Object` in js. You can see this by looking at the `__proto__` property in Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the reason is in the transpiled code:

```
var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || (function () {
    var extendStatics = Object.setPrototypeOf ||
        ({ __proto__: [] } instanceof Array && function (d, b) { d.__proto__ = b; }) ||
        function (d, b) { for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p]; };
    return function (d, b) {
        extendStatics(d, b);
        function __() { this.constructor = d; }
        d.prototype = b === null ? Object.create(b) : (__.prototype = b.prototype, new __());
    };
})();
var Person = /** @class */ (function (_super) {
    __extends(Person, _super);
    function Person() {
        return _super !== null && _super.apply(this, arguments) || this;
    }
    Person.prototype.toString = function () {
        return 'hi';
    };
    return Person;
}(Object));
var p = new Person();
```

As you see in the definition of the `Person` function (the constructor for `Person`) it is returning the result to calling `_super.apply(this, arguments)`.  So, in essence, is returning `Object()`, which is basically an empty object. And, besides, it's setting the prototype of the resulting object to that of `Object`, making in fact a direct descendant of Object and ignoring the `Person` prototype. In fact, if you execute the code in the console and you do:

```
p instanceof Person
```

You get `false`

And if you do

```
p.__proto__ === Object.prototype
```

you get `true`.

So never derive from `Object`. Implicitly, all objecs already do.

**But, why does this happen?**

Well, as we can see, the constructor returns `_super.apply(this, arguments) || this`.

This means that, if the calling to the constructor function without `new` returns `undefined` (the usual for almost all classes, whose constructors have no `return` statement) then we get `this`, and all works as expected.

The question is, by the ECMASCript specification, a constructor function returns `this` if the call to it (calling `.call()`) returns something that is not an object. That is not true for `Object()`, which returns an empty object, while most constructor functions just don't (as stated, they return `undefined`). So here, TypeScript is following the same convention, and, as `Object()` itself returns `{ }`, so does any derived class, only with augmented properties.

In the example, if you add a `name` property to `Person`, you could do:

```
const p = new Person();
p.name = 'John';
```

even if `p` is not of type `Person`, but rather, `Object`.

TypeScript transpilation makes constructors allways return `_this`. Usually, this is the same as `this` (what is implicitly returned by a constructor when you call with `new`), so no harm done. But, of course, this means that, if you execute the transpiled code in the console, you can do:

```
Person();
```

And it'll give you a nice empty object (exactly like `Object`, from which it dervies explicitly! In this way, the behaviour is logical).

If you add properties, like `name`, calling `Person()` will give you an object with such properties.

So, as more correct conclusion: don't derive from constructors that also work without `new` and you're not sure of what they do when called in such a fashion.

Comment: That is indeed what I see happening, the question is.. why? why not return this after just calling super.apply(this, arguments)?  so this would work:   function Person() {
        if (_super !== null) _super.apply(this, arguments); return this;
    }      and if it does work in ES6, this is inconsistent between transpile targets..

Comment: Edited response to explain why (more or less ...)